# Toilet leaking around tank bolts

Tags: toilet

After several adjustments, there is still water leakage around the bolts on the underside of the tank. Any thoughts?

Comment: How long has this been happening? If you edited your question to include a photo of the problem it might be easier to help. If you can't add a photo, post it on imgur.com and add a link to it in your question - someone will come along and add it in as a picture for you :)

Comment: What kind of adjustments? Sounds like the rubber washers under those bolt heads have deteriorated too far and need replaced.

Answer (score 4):

Tank bolt gaskets - every now and again (around 40 years on the last one I changed out) you have to remove the old crusty ones, clean things up, put on new ones, apply silicone grease if you know what's good for you, and reassemble.

If you just crank up the bolts instead you can crack the ceramic, and then it's new toilet time.